# Minimizing the scope of a variable in do ... while loop [Java] - ERROR: Symbol cannot be found

Tags: java, loops, scope, initialization, do-while

I would like to minimize the scope of `arr` to a `do ... while` loop, so it can be destroyed once the loop is exited.

If I declare `arr` *within* the `do while` loop, I get the error:

> symbol cannot be found

I can declare it right before the cycle, but then I keep bloated `arr` in memory even though I don't need it any more.

```
//int[] arr = {0}; // this works, but the scope is outside the loop
do {
    int[] arr = {0};  // causes "cannot find symbol" on `while` line
    arr = evolve(arr); // modifies array, saves relevant results elsewhere
    } while (arr.length < 9999);
```

What is the correct way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have:

- An initial state
- A terminating state
- An iterative operation

So you have everything needed to use a `for` loop (albeit without a body):

```
for (int[] arr = {0}; arr.length < 9999; arr = evolve(arr));
```

---

Another solution, but nowhere near as neat, is to add this *after* the loop:

```
arr = null;
```

which still allows the allocated memory to be garbage collected and has a similar practical effect to restricting scope. Sometimes you need this approach if you can't refactor the code another way.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of ways. You can declare `boolean` token outside of a cicle and check against it. You can encapsulate the whole thing in a method that ends right after `do while`.

Answer (score 2):

@Bohemian's solution is elegant.

But, if you still wan't to achieve this using do.. while, then following solution should work

```
    int l = 9999;
    do {
        int[] arr = { 0 }; // causes "cannot find symbol" on `while` line
        arr = evolve(arr); // modifies array, saves relevant results elsewhere
        l = arr.length;
    } while (l < 9999);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also define the array outside the do-while loop and wrap the whole thing in a small method. The array will then be garbage collected when the method ends. This also helps to structure your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option - although arguably not better than any of those already mentioned - would be to wrap it into a block:

```
{
    int[] arr = {0}; // this works, but the scope is outside the loop
    do {
        int[] arr = {0};
        arr = evolve(arr); // modifies array, saves relevant results elsewhere
    } while (arr.length < 9999);
}
```

I'd prefer @martinhh's solution though - just extract it to a method with a meaningful name.

The body-less for loop is fine, too - but it would probably be a good idea to leave a comment there that it was indeed intentional to omit the body - things like that tend to get highlighted by static analysis tools and may cause some confusion.